# i cannot Upload my MVC Project via VS Publish Tools, it only accept FTP

Tags: azure, deployment, ftp, publishing, webdeploy

i'm facing really frustrated problem with my project, i used to use Visual studio publish tools to Upload any web app or web site to Azure Through Visual Studio Publish Option,

but after i have work on some Project and try to Publish it through the same Option Witch is Publish Web Site to Azure.

the Application gives me an errors and shows that there are some missing files and directories.

### but when i connect to my ftp account on azure i can Upload site via Filezilla. the problem is i have dealing with filezilla and any other tools that makes the works too much slow and inefficient.

i have created a new web app on azure on this link `http://testloai.azurewebsites.net/`

here is the output when i publish it

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AwesomeMvcDemo, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  AwesomeMvcDemo -> C:\Users\loaia\Desktop\site_00061\site\AwesomeMvcDemo\bin\AwesomeMvcDemo.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: AwesomeMvcDemo, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://testloai.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=testloai ...
2>Adding directory (testloai\bin).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\bui).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\gui).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\gui2).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\gui3).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\met).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\start).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Content\themes\wui).
2>Adding directory (testloai\EDMX).
2>Adding directory (testloai\fonts).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Scripts).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Account).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\AddNewStudent).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\AddNewTasmie).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Classes).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\ClassesGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Error).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Groups).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\GroupsGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Home).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\MasterDetailCrudDemo).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\MealCustomSearchLookup).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Mosques).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\MosquesGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Permissions).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\PermissionsGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Shared).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Sitemap).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Students).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\StudentsGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\SupervisionCenters).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\SupervisionCentersGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Tasmies).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\TasmiesGridCrud).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\Users).
2>Adding directory (testloai\Views\UsersGridCrud).
2>Adding ACL's for path (testloai)
2>Adding ACL's for path (testloai)
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\AwesomeMvcDemo.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\EntityFramework.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\NPOI.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\NPOI.OOXML.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Omu.Awem.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Omu.AwesomeMvc.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Omu.ValueInjecter.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\Owin.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Http.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.Razor.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\bin\WebGrease.dll).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\awedemo.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\bootstrap-rtl.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\bootstrap.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\circlelogo.jpg).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\common.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\jquery-1.12.4.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\jquery-ui.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\jquery-ui.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\jquery.validate.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\js.cookie.min.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\logo.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\o.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\prettify.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\run_prettify.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\black-cab\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\bui\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\bui\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\bui\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\bui\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\bui\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui2\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui2\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui2\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui2\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui2\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui3\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui3\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui3\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui3\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\gui3\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\met\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\met\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\met\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\met\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\met\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\start\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\start\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\start\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\start\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\start\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\awem.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\AwesomeMvc.css).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\awe_icons.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\editdel.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\loading.gif).
2>Adding file (testloai\Content\themes\wui\pm.png).
2>Adding file (testloai\EDMX\Model1.edmx.diagram).
2>Adding file (testloai\f.ico).
2>Adding file (testloai\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot).
2>Adding file (testloai\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg).
2>Adding file (testloai\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf).
2>Adding file (testloai\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff).
2>Adding file (testloai\Global.asax).
2>Adding file (testloai\packages.config).
2>Adding file (testloai\Scripts\awem.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Scripts\AwesomeMvc.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Scripts\Site.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Scripts\utils.js).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Delete.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Edit.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Login.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Manage.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\Register.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\UserGroups.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\UserPermissions.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Account\_SetPasswordPartial.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\AddNewStudent\AddNewStudent.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\AddNewStudent\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\AddNewTasmie\AddNewTasmie.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\AddNewTasmie\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Classes\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Classes\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\ClassesGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\ErrorPartial.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\Expected.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\ExpectedPartial.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\HttpError401.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\HttpError404.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Error\HttpError505.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Groups\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Groups\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\GroupsGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Home\About.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Home\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\MasterDetailCrudDemo\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\MealCustomSearchLookup\SearchForm.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Mosques\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Mosques\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\MosquesGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Permissions\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Permissions\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\PermissionsGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\Delete.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Boolean.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ButtonGroupCheckbox.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ButtonGroupRadio.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ColorDropdown.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Combobox.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Hidden.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Int32.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\LookupDropdown.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\MealsOdropdown.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\MultiLookupDropdown.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Multiselect.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Odropdown.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ReadOnly.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Single.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Textarea.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\TimePicker.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\TimePickerm.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\_FieldLayout.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\LoginLayout.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Sitemap\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Sitemap\parent.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Students\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\StudentsGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\SupervisionCenters\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\SupervisionCenters\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\SupervisionCentersGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Tasmies\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Tasmies\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\TasmiesGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\TasmiesGridCrud\LunchDetail.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Users\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Users\Index.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\UsersGridCrud\Create.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\Web.config).
2>Adding file (testloai\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml).
2>Adding file (testloai\Web.config).
2>Adding ACL's for path (testloai)
2>Adding ACL's for path (testloai)
2>Publish Succeeded.
2>Web App was published successfully http://testloai.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

but after this success msg also the web site not working on azure

do you have any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any screen-capture of the error?

I am not sure if the following link would be of help - http://www.mihirmone.com/post/error-while-publishing-your-web-app-to-azure-using-visual-studio

Comment: i have create a test website on azure `http://testloai.azurewebsites.net/` and i have publish it via visual studio publish tools. i will post the output to the post

Comment: yes but you cannot see anything it gives you an Error Http 500

Comment: and i don't why it's redirects me to the `http://testloai.azurewebsites.net/Error/HttpError401?ReturnUrl=%2f`

Comment: I tried to browse the link - http://testloai.azurewebsites.net/, it routes to Error page (MVC page routing). When a blank webapp is created in Azure, it shows a default page. There seem to be an issue with the project. Does it work on your local machine?

Comment: yes it's working fine without any problem, and btw this is not the first time i publish mvc project to azure. but in this project there are some problem idk exactly.

Comment: Error code 401, also means unauthorized access to IIS resource. Is it ok to delete the webapp from Azure and, deploy it directly from Visual Studio (If you use Visual Studio-Publish, it will create a new WebApp for you and deploy your application code)

Comment: and btw the main problem here is the when i try to publish/Upload the site using FileZilla it's working fine.

Comment: Some files may be missing!

Comment: i will try to create an app service from the visual studio it self to upload the site to it.

Comment: but anyhow, i don't sure that some files are missing Bcs, i have try all the possilibe options for that and still not working when using Visual Studio Publish tools (only in this project)

Comment: as i told you i have try to create a webapp from the vs it self here is the link `loaitestnum2.azurewebsites.net` some problem appears again

Comment: Please check if "Anonymous Access" is enabled. Project -> Properties

Comment: its Enabled, i didn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131881/discussion-between-mihir-and-loai).